# How to prevent pop-up upon html page load

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML5 (jsp) page with a link (here) to another page which has a link on it (Home) that, when clicked, pops up a message.  However, the message pops up when the page is loaded, which is undesirable.  Would someone please look at the below code and give me a solution/suggestion as to how to prevent this behavior?   Thank you.

HTML link on first page:

```
<td class="align-left">Click <a href="javascript:fnCallActionOnSelf('newpage.htm')">here</a></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function fnCallActionOnSelf(actionName)
{
    if(actionName == "newpage.htm"){
        nullPageValues();  //here link does not like special characters like apostrophes being sent over by the GET     
    }
    document.forms[0].method = "GET";
    document.forms[0].target = '';
    document.forms[0].action = actionName;
    document.forms[0].submit(); 
}
function nullPageValues() {
    //This is for the here link because it does not like special characters like apostrophes being sent over by the GET
    document.getElementById('textField1').value="";
    document.getElementById('password').value="";
    document.getElementById('Name').value="";
    document.getElementById('Address').value="";
    document.getElementById('City').value="";   
    document.getElementById('PhoneNumber').value="";    
}
</script>
```

Jsp page that here link points to:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE; chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" http-equiv="Cache-Control">
<meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="Pragma">
<meta content="0" http-equiv="Expires">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <center>
            <div style="width: 960px;">
                <div>
                    <div id="Help"
                        style="vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;">
                        <jsp:include page="Help.jsp">
                            <jsp:param name="isHome" value="no" />
                        </jsp:include>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
    <form:form method="post" name="newform" 
        id="newform" commandName="newformModel" data-parsley-validate="true">
    </form:form>
<!-- Lots of stuff here -->
    <script src="/project/js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/project/js/scripts.js" type="JavaScript"></script>
    <script src="/project/js/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/project/js/civem.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/project/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/project/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/project/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/project/js/plugin.js"></script>
    <script src="/spiaprojectweb/js/validation.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
      });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Home link jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("click","a[name='lnkViews']", function (e) {
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
});
function fnCallActionOnSelf(actionName) {
    document.forms[0].target = '';
    document.forms[0].method = "POST";
    document.forms[0].action = actionName;    <script>
    document.forms[0].submit(); 
}
function openWindow(anchor)
{       
    window.open(anchor,'NewWindow','status=0,toolbar=0,resizable=yes,scrollbars=1,width=800,height=600');   
}
function findPosition( oElement )
{
    oElement=document.getElementById(oElement); 
    if( typeof( oElement.offsetParent ) != 'undefined' )
    {
        for( var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent )
        {
            posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
            posY += oElement.offsetTop;
        }
        return posX;
    }
    else
    {
        return posX;
    }
}
var timeout         = 0;
var closetimer      = 0;
var ddmenuitem      = 0;

// open hidden layer
function mopen(id)
{
    // cancel close timer   
    mcancelclosetime();

    // close old layer
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';              
    ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
    var salesAidesPos=findPosition('salesLiId');
    salesAidesPos-=20;      
    ddmenuitem.style.left=salesAidesPos+'px';
    ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
function mopenHelp(id)
{
    // cancel close timer   
    mcancelclosetime();

    // close old layer
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';              
    ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
    var salesAidesPos=findPosition('helpId');
    salesAidesPos-=40;      
    ddmenuitem.style.left=salesAidesPos+'px';
    ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
// close showed layer
function mclose()
{
    if(ddmenuitem)
    {
        ddmenuitem.style.left='0px';
         ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}

// go close timer
function mclosetime()
{
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
}

// cancel close timer
function mcancelclosetime()
{
    if(closetimer)
    {
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;
    }
}

// close layer when click-out
document.onclick = mclose; 
</script>

<div id="navcontainer" class="header">
    <span class="headtitle"></span> <span class="utility">
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <span id="helpId">
                <li class=""><a name='lnkViews' href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseout="mclosetime()"
                    onmouseover="javascript: mopenHelp('helpDiv');">Help</a></li>
            </span>
        </ul>
    </span>
</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Help"  style="display:none;">
  <p><b>Help Message</b></p>
</div>
<div id="spacer">
    <img src="/project/img/spacer.gif" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setUpdateMessagePosition(oElement) {
        oElement = document.getElementById(oElement);
        if (typeof (oElement.offsetParent) != 'undefined') {
            for ( var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent) {
                posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
                posY += oElement.offsetTop;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("updateMsg") != null) {
                posX = posX + 8;
                posY = posY + 3;
                document.getElementById("updateMsg").style.left = posX + "px";
                document.getElementById("updateMsg").style.top = posY + "px";
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know what much of the above means, or whether it is necessary, but it seems to me that all the action (the code of interest) is in the below snippets from the above jsp file:

```
<script>
$(document).on("click","a[name='lnkViews']", function (e) {
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
});
</script>

                <li class=""><a name='lnkViews' href="javascript:void(0);" onmouseout="mclosetime()"
                    onmouseover="javascript: mopenHelp('helpDiv');">Help</a></li>

<div id="dialog" title="Help"  style="display:none;">
  <p><b>Help Message</b></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good time for using sessionStorage! You can do it like this. Change this part of your code:

```
       <script>
        $(document).on("click","a[name='lnkViews']", function (e) {
        $(function() {
           $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
         });
         });
      </script>
```

to this:

```
        <script>
        $(document).on("click","a[name='lnkViews']", function (e) {
        $(function() {
         if (sessionStorage.visitedalready) {
            sessionStorage.visitedalready= 1;
         }
      else{
         $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
       }});});
      </script>
```

That session storage variable will be automatically removed once your session was ended.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Vance, but it didn't work for me.  The problem is that it still pops up when the page is loaded.  I need it to not pop up on load of the page.  Thanks for looking at it, though.

Comment: I have taken out all of the extraneous code from the included jsp page.  It looks to me like the style display:none in the div is not working on page load.  Below is the simplified Help.jsp page:

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    $(document).on("click","a[name='lnkViews']", function (e) {
    $(function() {
     if (sessionStorage.visitedalready) {
        sessionStorage.visitedalready= 1;
     }
  else{
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
   }});});
  </script>
```

Comment: Code is nice, but code with an explanation is substantially more useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this worked, but I changed the name of my div to an id and renamed the id to helpDialog and changed to use that in the $(document).on function.  Then I got rid of the 'e' in the function parameter list for the function in the $(document).on parameter list.  That fixed the problem.  I'm not sure which of these did the trick.